# The best overload for 'CryptoStream' does not have a parameter named 'leaveOpen'

Tags: c#, android, encryption, xamarin.forms, cryptostream

There is an variable named **leaveOpen** in **cryptostream** which is available in **windows ** but not in **xamarin**. If true then stream won't be close automatically.

```
return new CryptoStream(
    stream: FileStream,
    transform: AES.CreateDecryptor(),
    mode: CryptoStreamMode.Read,
    leaveOpen: true       
);
```

[image]

[image]

So my problem is that argument which is not available in **Xamarin**. So whats the problem and how can solve it ? I have many alternatives but I want to use that only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change target framework of your share project to .NetStandard **2.1**.

Right click your forms project --> Properties -> Application --> Target framework:

[image]

```
    CryptoStream  stream = new CryptoStream(
        stream: FileStream,
        transform: AES.CreateDecryptor(),
        mode: CryptoStreamMode.Read,
        leaveOpen: true
    );
```

The document is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=netstandard-2.1).

Comment: Hi first special thanks for doing such great research. But I have some doubts.

Comment: (1) My project is not showing 2.1 or upper standards even installing .net Core runtimes + sdk for development.

Comment: (2) The doc link you have sent says that it also available to these .net standards: 2.1,2.0,1.6,1.4,1.3. So my current version is 2.0.

Comment: 1. Are you using the latest visual-studio 2019?  2. No, if I change to .netstandard 2.0, there is only one constructor there, see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=netstandard-2.0). Available there means CryptoStream is available.

Comment: So now what will you recommend ? (1) I am using VS2017 15.9.26. (2)Yes right I got it.

Comment: I would recommend to use a VS2019:).

Comment: I also wanted to use 2019. But my pc don't allow me to do this. VS2019 is heavy and has unsolvable errors.

Comment: No, VS2019 is not heavy and it is new with many features which 2017 does not have. You will finally switch to VS2019 in the future.

Comment: @MuhammadAli If my answer helps you, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Hi I have less ram pc, So I can verify that VS17 is more simple and fast loadup. I don't extra features if it can even build an apk. I will switch if I have good pc.
You can see my errors in VS19 here https://stackoverflow.com/q/63187550/11390822

Comment: Looks logical so making it tick

Comment: Well, I would say visual-studio 2019 is the future:). You can do some research to check if there is any way to let Visual-studio 2017 support .netstandard 2.1.